# Switching SDK Version Causes App not to Build?

Tags: android, tensorflow, sdk, android-manifest

I'm working on my first app and started with the Tensorflow Pose Estimation Start Code. I was able to make something I thought was pretty cool but in order to put it on the app store you have to use an targetSdkVersion greater than the starter code. I changed it from 30 to 33.

Unfortunately, after changing this the project will no longer build.

Error:

```
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED
***FILE Name Hidden *** 
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyFloatingActivity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.


See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
 Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I attempted to look at my Merge Manifest and there are two warnings but I have no idea what to do with these:

```
 Merge Warnings 

Warning: Namespace 'org.tensorflow.lite' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. tensorflow-lite:2.7.0 manifest 

Warning: Namespace 'org.tensorflow.lite.support' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. tensorflow-lite-support:0.3.0 manifest
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out the solution, the androidTestImplementations needed to be updated in the gradle!